# ¿Cómo desarrollar un método que pueda utilizar los atributos de dos objetos de la misma clase en C++ correctamente?

Tags: c++, poo, clase, objeto, método

Quiero desarrollar un método el cual pueda imprimir dos atributos de dos objetos de una misma clase.

El objeto en cuestión es un número complejo, sus atributos son un número real y un número imaginario, y lo que quiero que imprima es lo siguiente:

```
//Objeto #1
Complejo punto1(1, 2);

//Objeto #2
Complejo punto1(3, 4);

//Y lo que imprima sería:
(1 + 2i) + (3 + 4i)
```

La cosa está en la única forma que conozco de diseñar un método que pueda hacer eso es de dos maneras:

1. Utilizar sólo los atributos de la clase de un solo objeto (el cual no me sirve, pues debo de imprimir los 2 atributos de esos 2 objetos).
2. Diseñar un método el cual pueda albergar 4 parámetros, y de allí reemplazar cada uno de los parámetros con un método que pueda obtener cada uno de los de los puntos, pero eso lo tendría que hacer en el main y eso tampoco me sirve, así fue cómo lo hice:

```
void Complejo::getSuma(int r1, int i1, int r2, int i2){
  cout<<"("<<r1<<" + "<<i1<<"i) + ("<<r2<<" + "<<i2<<"i)"<<endl;
 }
```

¿Qué se podría desarrollar un método el cual pueda operar atributos de 2 objetos de una misma clase?

A continuación les dejo el código que utilicé

```
//Complejo.h

#ifndef COMPLEJO_H_
#define COMPLEJO_H_

class Complejo{
  private:
    int real, imaginario;

  public:
    Complejo(int r, int i);

    ~Complejo();

    int getReal();

    int getImaginario();

    void getSuma(int r1, int i1, int r2, int i2);

    void getResta(int r1, int i1, int r2, int i2);

 
}; 

#endif

//---------------------------------------------------------

//Complejo.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "Complejo.h"
using namespace std;
Complejo::Complejo(int r, int i){
  real = r;
  imaginario = i;
}

Complejo::~Complejo(){

}
 
int Complejo::getReal(){
  return real;
}

int Complejo::getImaginario(){
  return imaginario;
}

void Complejo::getSuma(int r1, int i1, int r2, int i2){
  if(i1<0){
    cout<<"("<<r1<<" - "<<-1*i1<<"i) + ("<<r2<<" + "<<i2<<"i)"<<endl;
  }

  if(i2<0){
    cout<<"("<<r1<<" + "<<i1<<"i) + ("<<r2<<" - "<<-1*i2<<"i)"<<endl;
  }

  else{ 
    cout<<"("<<r1<<" + "<<i1<<"i) + ("<<r2<<" + "<<i2<<"i)"<<endl;
  }
  
}

void Complejo::getResta(int r1, int i1, int r2, int i2){
  if(i1<0){
    cout<<"("<<r1<<" - "<<-1*i1<<"i) - ("<<r2<<" + "<<i2<<"i)"<<endl;
  }

  if(i2<0){
    cout<<"("<<r1<<" + "<<i1<<"i) - ("<<r2<<" - "<<-1*i2<<"i)"<<endl;
  }

  else{ 
    cout<<"("<<r1<<" + "<<i1<<"i) - ("<<r2<<" + "<<i2<<"i)"<<endl;
  }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

//main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "Complejo.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int r, i;

  Complejo punto1(7, 8);
  Complejo punto2(12, 2);
  Complejo punto3(5, 3);
  Complejo punto4(-3, 3);
  Complejo punto5(7, -2);

  


  cout<<punto1.getReal()<<" + "<<punto1.getImaginario()<<"i"<<endl;

  cout<<punto2.getReal()<<" + "<<punto2.getImaginario()<<"i"<<endl;

  cout<<punto3.getReal()<<" + "<<punto3.getImaginario()<<"i"<<endl;

  cout<<endl;

  punto5.getSuma(-3,3,7,-2);
  
  punto5.getResta(-3, 3, 7, -2);



  

  return 0;
}
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es más facil si divides el problema complejo en otros más sencillos.

Por un lado puedes implementar un método `toString()` en `Complejo`:

```
class Complejo{
public:

    std::string toString() const
    {
      if( imaginario < 0 )
      {
        return "(" + std::to_string(real) + " - " + std::to_string(-imaginario) + "i)";
      }
      else
      {
        return "(" + std::to_string(real) + " + " + std::to_string(imaginario) + "i)";
      }
    }
};
```

Y ya solo tienes que apoyarte en dicho método para conseguir tus propósitos al hacer operaciones:

```
void getSuma(Complejo const& c1, Complejo const& c2)
{
  cout << c1.toString() << " + " << c2.toString() << '\n';
}
```

O incluso podrías generalizar más aún la solución si la función devolviese un string:

```
std::string getSuma(Complejo const& c1, Complejo const& c2)
{
  return c1.toString() + " + " + c2.toString() + '\n';
}
```

Así podrías usar esa cadena para mostrarla por pantalla, almacenarla en un archivo, sacarla por la impresora, enviarla por un socket, ...

```
Complejo complejo1, complejo2;
// ...
std::cout << getSuma(complejo1, complejo2);
```

Nota que no tiene sentido que `getSuma` sea una función miembro de `Complejo` ya que no estás aprovechando las variables del objeto. Si podría llegar a tener sentido que se tratase de un método estático:

```
class Complejo
{
public:
  static std::string getSuma(Complejo const& c1, Complejo const& c2);
};
```

Al hacer la función estática ahora tendríamos que llamarla así:

```
Complejo::getSuma(c1, c2);
```

Comment: Sabes cómo incluir la variable const? Apenas estoy empezando con C++

Comment: @LauraP. No entiendo tu pregunta

Comment: No, ya no hace falta, todo lo que explicaste quedó bien clarín.

Comment: Muchas gracias <3
Por cierto, para implementar ese método estático sólo tendría que añadir el `static` en el método `getSuma` ?

Comment: @LauraP. correcto